# How to do a range index and match or vlookup in power pivot excel?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot

These are the individual data points of the `data model`:

[image]

These are the monthly salaries of the employees (obtained using the pivot table from the data model's data):

[image]

Each cell will then be used as the Lookup value which will be run through a table.

The lookup value is to be looked up in `column A` and `column B` of the table below and if it is matched (within the range), it will return the corresponding value under `column C`.

[image]

I am unable to find any `index and match` or `vlookup` functions in the power pivot functionality of excel using `measures`--which are used to get some analytics on aggregated values on report objects such as pivot tables.

I have found `LOOKUPVALUE( <result_columnName>, <search_columnName>, <search_value>[, <search_columnName>, <search_value>]…)` which is a `DAX` function however, the issue here is that I am doing a **range lookup** and as shown below, I don't know if you can have an array as an argument to the function.
[image]

Traditional `calculated fields` also do not allow arrays in the formulas.

`Lookupvalue()` only works on a single column lookups because it will return an empty cell if it cannot find a match as shown below:

[image]

But when it does find a match using the table below:

[image]

It will work just fine:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a measure for Pay:

```
Total Pay = SUM(Table1[Pay])
```

It's important to do it as a measure instead of just dropping 'Pay' into a pivot table (this is called an 'implicit measure' and is concidered a bad practice).

Then, let's say your table with pay ranges is named "Pay Ranges". Create another measure:

```
Returned Value = 
CALCULATE( 
VALUES('Pay Ranges'[Value To Return]), 
FILTER( 'Pay Ranges', 
[Total Pay] >= 'Pay Ranges'[Lower Bound] &&
[Total Pay] <  'Pay Ranges'[Upper Bound]
))
```

Make sure that all these formulas are Measures, not calculated columns. 
Also, the formula relies on the correct construction of the ranges. If they overlap, you will get an error.